# Highlight not working along with term lookup filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search and have started exploring it from the past few days. My requirement is to get the matched keywords highlighted.

So I have 2 indices

```
http://localhost:9200/lookup/type/1?pretty
Output
{
"_index" : "lookup",
"_type" : "type",
"_id" : "1",
"_version" : 1,
"found" : true,
"_source":{"terms":["Apache
Storm","Kafka","MR","Pig","Hive","Hadoop","Mahout"]}
}
```

And another one as following:-

```
http://localhost:9200/skillsetanalyzer/resume/_search?fields=keySkills
output
{"took":19,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"skillsetanalyzer","_type":"resume","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"fields":{"keySkills":["Core
Java","J2EE","Struts 1.x","SOAP based
Web Services using JAX-WS","Maven","Ant","JMS","Apache
Storm","Kafka","RDBMS
(MySQL","Tomcat","Weblogic","Eclipse","Toad","TIBCO
product Suite (Administrator","Business
Work","Designer","EMS)","CVS","SVN"]}},
```

And below query returns the correct results but does not highlight the matched keywords.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/skillsetanalyzer/resume/_search?pretty' -d '
{

"query":
{"filtered":
       {"filter":
         {"terms":
            {"keySkills":
                {"index":"lookup",
                  "type":"type",
                   "id":"1",
                  "path":"terms"
                },
            "_cache_key":"1"
        }
      }
   }
},
"highlight": {
         "fields":{
              "keySkills":{}
              }
    }
}'
```

Field "KeySkills" is not analyzed and its type is String. I'm not able to make out what is wrong with the
query.
Please help in providing the necessary pointers.

~Shweta

Answer (score 0):

[Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) works against the **Query**, you are just **filtering** the results. You need to specify `highlight_query` along with your filters like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "keySkills": [
            "MR","Pig","Hive"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "keySkills": {
        "highlight_query": {
          "terms": {
            "keySkills": [
              "MR","Pig","Hive"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.